# How to inspire team member to do project task effectively while they are busy with their daily task?

Tags: team-management, project-management-style, project-team

I'm working on a new project that currently has only me to lead it, so I often have to ask for help from some members from other department units.

I already set a timeline and scheduled a task for each member assignee to complete their task. However, because there are additional tasks for them, they do not have enough time to do it for me; they are busy with their daily tasks, so the project is running late.

I could not force them or use bossy words in order for them to do it because I am the one that's going to ask them for help. Still, I need the project to be on the schedule timeline set.

My question is: how can I make this project be on its timeline schedule, since now it is running late because other departments' assignees are already busy doing their daily tasks? It also might be that they do not want to help me or something.

Any advice or suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression *run behind schedule* exists and is used to describe something that as high risk to or is actually going to arrive / leave later than the time that is expected. This can also be applied to projects.

In your case, you answer to someone, there's agreed SMART objectives defined but workers aren't able to cope with it. Consequently, the project is behind schedule and not in budget.

It's great you try and understand the forces driving the project off schedule but the problem, from what I read, isn't necessarily the workers doing multitasking and losing productivity. It can be yours if the schedule didn't consider uncertainties and unknowns, or of someone pulling your team off project, or all (Just a few examples).

It's normal the initial plan changes. You should re-plan and find the problem, the possible solutions for that problem and be all eyes to understand the outcomes of the applied solution, so that you learn from it and you're able to deliver what was promised. This requires also communication from your side because the project is only happening because someone wants and that someone should be updated. That's what project management is about.

Comment: thanks so much. I am thinking if I can get involve helping to do for them in this case. However, I was trying to insist them if they are having any problem our project task or not, I tried all way to explain what to do and how to do, but some still say they don't know what to do. I'm, a project leader, need to hear the updated from them and if any problem to solve it immediately, but some still keep silent and no updated. Thanks

Comment: «As a PM your job isn't to do or manage technical work, it is to make sure that the people who are responsible for the doing and managing are following the plan.

What you need are clear accountabilities for the deliverables.»

Comment: Read more here: https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6250/27189

Comment: Thanks I've got the point you mentioned, I will do this in the phase II of my project. However, for taking worker into plan making, the deadline of the project because the starting date and ending date of project has already been defined. if the meeting session with workers was not agreed with deadline or their concern is solved by extending the timeline of ending date, it would be a problem. Thanks

Comment: Beware if you don't do development you shouldn't do estimates. Too many managers get together with the customer and promise impossible timelines, then expect the devs to live up to their outrageous promises. Then feel the need to fire lead devs. Just like Elon Musk, https://www.theinformation.com/articles/frustrated-musk-shakes-up-autopilot-team

Comment: after reading through out this, I got some ideas what I should do next. I admitted that I did not consider those risks when making a plan, however for Phase II of this project, I will this take this into account and your better suggestion. Thanks so much for helping me; I am a newbie to PM.

Comment: The majority of what I just shared was learned here reading QAs from other users. There's highly skilled professionals helping on a daily basis. It's a bless.

Comment: thanks, currently I will have to deal with problem that one department units of 3 members, which 2 of them currently very busy their own daily task leave all leftover task of my project handle by one person of their unit. I don't know if she could handle all of that by herself alone because it's many; and how I could share them with members from other units to help because Phase II of project is one/two days arriving and all members has to do for Phase II also. Thanks